# How to set tomcat specific properties on grails

Tags: tomcat, grails, intellij-idea

I want to be able to set some tomcat properties in grails. Specifically I want to set org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true system property. (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html) but I have no idea where these config go.

I have tried setting it Run -> Edit Configurations as Command Line arguments, VM options, and setting CATALINA_OPTS as an environment variable. But none work. And I'm not even sure how to check whether these values are being read.

I am running grails 2.1.0 with the tomcat grails plugin running on IntelliJ on Mac OSX.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can view what properties are being passed to the app with the [application info plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/app-info).

Another option would be connecting to the running grails application with Java VisualVM which is generally bundled with the jdk.  Check the bin directory of your java installation for jvisualvm.

To pass properties, have a look at the [docs for run-app](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-app.html) Are you specifying the property correctly?

Comment: Thanks. I believe I'm setting the property correctly. This is what it looks like on IntelliJ when it starts:   /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:... "run-app --stacktrace --verbose -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true"

Comment: If memory serves correct, the order is significant.  run-app must appear after the property settings.

Comment: I tried changing the order but still the same results. Is there a a file like catalina.properties where I can do this?

Comment: Did you verify with visual vm, or try on the console outside of intellij?